# Selenium java how to get text from element in second quotes ""

Tags: java, selenium, element, quotes, gettext

```
<div class="_2b9p7-6Tcy_ja6zEhxML2e">
   <div class="flex _1VLiOJeD-kdBBLC9owCkQr">
    <span class="flex-1">”Total””:”</span>
    <span>
           “USD” 
           “2,175”
    </span>
```

Need to get the text inly in second quotes "", in this case "“2,175”", and I do not know how to do it.
Both “USD” and “2,175” comes from API (they are different every time, hence I can't use driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath and not 'USD'), I can split the result, and take only the necessary part, but I would like to know a way how to take the value from only the second brackets for the future (2,175).
I had performed the following on Intellij

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = '_2b9p7-6Tcy_ja6zEhxML2e']//div//span/following-sibling:: span")).getText());
```

and getting, of course, full text - USD 2,175, but I need 2,175

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value **2,175** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *xpath* and *following*:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Total')]//following::span[1]")));
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *following-sibling*:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Total')]//following-sibling::span[1]")));
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString());
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not apply to my question, I know the path to the element, I do not need to wait in this case, I can print it, I do not need the whole text, but only the part that is in the second quotation marks, I can't use "textContent"(because of API), and I do not need JavascriptExecutor in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = '_2b9p7-6Tcy_ja6zEhxML2e']//div//span/following-sibling:: span")).getText().substring(7, 11);
```

You can use substring in two ways:

> String substring(int begIndex)
>
> String substring​(int beginIndex, intendIndex)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good way, in my case it works, but I’m interested in how I can separate the text if, for example, in quotation marks there would be a different number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use split on the returned string like shown below.

```
String[] amount = returnedText.split(" ");
```

amount[1] should be your required text.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good way, in my case it works, but I’m interested in how I can separate the text if, for example, in quotation marks there would be characters with spaces. I think that selenium does not see quotes, but maybe there is some way through javascript or something else.